# sendmail From empty when relaying

Tags: sendmail

When sending a mail logged in as `ec2-user` to an unknown user:

```
echo "Subject: test" | /usr/lib/sendmail -v abc
```

the `From:<>` is blank when redirected to ec2-user's alias which is causing the external server to reject the mail. Even setting `-f "ec2-user@internal"` doesn't fix it.

Inside my `/etc/aliases` I have

```
root:     webmaster@external
ec2-user: webmaster@external
```

The verbose output displays the following:

```
abc... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 internal ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4; Thu, 24 Mar 2016 16:42:37 GMT
>>> EHLO internal
250-internal Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> MAIL From:<ec2-user@internal> SIZE=14
250 2.1.0 <ec2-user@internal>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<abc@internal>
>>> DATA
550 5.1.1 <abc@internal>... User unknown
503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Reset state
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Reset state
ec2-user... Using cached ESMTP connection to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
>>> MAIL From:<> SIZE=1038
250 2.1.0 <>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<ec2-user@internal>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <ec2-user@internal>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
250 2.0.0 u2OGgbZL022963 Message accepted for delivery
ec2-user... Sent (u2OGgbZL022963 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 internal closing connection
```

When I send a mail to a known user, such as to the `ec2-user` or `root`, the mail is received.

How can I configure `sendmail` to set the `From` address when relaying in this way?

Comment: I would recommend using the `mailx` command (often installed as `mail`) to ensure a properly formatted message rather than calling sendmail directly from the command line

Comment: @HBruijn - Thanks. This is however on an Amazon Linux server with whatever is default installed

Comment: I don't have access to an Amazon instance but mail/mailx ought to be installed by default as far as I know. But your problem is that although sendmail sets the envelope sender correctly you don't provide a correct message (the combo of headers and message body) that gets transmitted as SMTP DATA, so you should do something along the lines of `echo -e "From: user@host\nSubject: your subject\n\nyour message body" | sendmail`

Comment: @HBruijn - I tried that, same problem. In fact I tried this article http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/support/Setting_From_and_Bounce_Address_on_Email_From_Websites

Answer (score 0):

OK - its actually to do with the bounce policy

```
5.2.9 Command Syntax: RFC-821 Section 4.1.2 

The syntax shown in RFC-821 for the MAIL FROM: command omits the case of an empty path: "MAIL 
FROM: <>" (see RFC-821 Page 15). An empty reverse path MUST be supported. 

5.3.3 Reliable Mail Receipt 
....... 
If there is a delivery failure after acceptance of a message, the receiver-SMTP MUST formulate 
and mail a notification message. This notification MUST be sent using a null ("<>") reverse 
path in the envelope; see Section 3.6 of RFC-821. The recipient of this notification SHOULD be 
the address from the envelope return path (or the Return-Path: line). However, if this address 
is null ("<>"), the receiver-SMTP MUST NOT send a notification. If the address is an explicit 
source route, it SHOULD be stripped down to its final hop.
```

Also on WIKI

```
Bounce messages in SMTP are sent with the envelope sender address <>, known as the null sender address.
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message